# convert dynamic to seo friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there is plenty on this issue in SO and elsewhere, and I read it all by now, but I do not seem to get this to work despite sweating it out all day.

So, see if you guys can point me in the right direction.

I have a dynamically created url ( by customer selecting a form at index.php ) that looks like, as an instance:

```
http://www.example.com/marques.php?brand_id=39-Ford
```

I need it to show to the user and search engines as:

```
www.example.com/marques/Ford
```

I have set up .htaccess as follows:

```
...other .htaccess stuff..
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/marques #here, I believe, to apply this only when URI is /marques
RewriteRule /([A-Z][a-z]+$)/ marques/$1  [L] #here I meant to get 'Ford' in this instance.
```

I plan to have the destination file, marques.php handle the request with the given brand info.

This is not working at all. I continue to see the 'old' URL.

Of course, the next step would be to have the .htaccess redirect when the customer clicks on the 'friendly' link at the search engine ( hopefully soon ). But I need the first step to be resolved.

By the way, I checked with my provider and they confirm that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot mask `39` in friendly URL. Otherwise how will your content will be loaded?

Comment: @anubhava, well, I have the brand name (Ford), if not the id (39). I should be able to retrieve the data from the server with that.

Comment: So `http://www.example.com/marques.php?brand_id=Ford` will be able to load the correct page also?

Comment: why don't you just make your app understand the URLs you want?

Comment: @anubhava. Put in that way, yes, as long as I have either the id or the brand name. But, this may be one of the crucial issues here ( and I am looking at your recently posted answer as I write this). I understood that the rewrite used this way would only show the 'friendly' URL on the browser , but still go to the dynamic one. It seems I misunderstood it completely.

Comment: @Eevee, interesting thought, but how would I accomplish that? I still starting from a GET request which will automatically generate the '?' as well as demand the marques.php file name.

Comment: My answer will externally redirect `/marques.php?brand_id=Ford` to `/marques/Ford` and will internally rewrite `/marques/Ford` to `/marques.php?brand_id=Ford`.

Comment: with php, i don't know.  but you may notice that, say, SO's URLs don't contain `?` or a file extension, and it's definitely not done with rewriting.  have your app take over the entire domain and parse paths itself; i'm sure there are libs or frameworks to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I realized I fell for this widespread misconception that one can use mod_rewrite to create SEO friendly URL's. Unfortunately, this misconception is reinforced throughout SO as well.

After reading [this article from Matthew James Taylor](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-post-forms-to-clean-rewritten-urls) and [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/6079.htm)  it became clear that one has to create the SEO friendly URL elsewhere, not through mod_rewrite, as was my thinking.

Mod_rewrite is ONLY part of the process.

If one has only links with anchor tags, one has to go in each page of the website and hardcode the change to the SEO friendly URL. In my case, the URL's are created dynamically.

May be there are alternative solutions, but this did the trick.

So, first I changed my form, from this:

```
<form action="marques.php " method="post" class="form1" >
<select class="select_home" name="brand_id" onchange="form.submit()" >
<option value= "<?php echo $row['brand_id']; ?>">"<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>"</option>
```

To this new set up:

```
 <form action=" " method="post" class="form1" >
 <select class="select_home" name="brand" onchange="form.submit()" >
 <option value= "<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>">"<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>"</option>
```

What I am doing above is submitting the form to the page itself by placing action = " "  and changing name and value to 'brand' ie, the name of the brand as opposed to the brand_id. This last one is meant to have the URL 'really' friendly. One can decide to have both the name and the id in the URL.

The SEO friendly URL is 'created' in the sequence. This script is placed at the very top of the same page, before anything else, otherwise 'header' will not work.

```
if(isset($_POST['brand'])){
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$brand = str_replace(" ", "-", $brand);
$url = '/marques-voiture/' . $brand;
header("Location:" .$url );
exit();
}
```

So, in the above the SEO friendly URL is created and will show at the browser:

```
www.example.com/marques/Ford or www.example.com/Land-Rover
```

Next, now yes, with mod_rewrite tell the browser how to make sense of that URL and fetch the right script which is:

```
www.example.com/marques.php?brand=Ford
```

I made that as follows within .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?marques-voiture [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([\-A-Za-z]+$) /marques.php?brand=$1 [L]
```

Of course it is necessary to change the destination script to receive a GET, instead of a POST which now contains the brand and not the brand_id as before.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+marques\.php\?brand_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /marques/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^marques/([^/.]+)/?$ marques.php?brand_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This will not work, at least not in the dynamic to friendly direction. If I do not have a file extension (marques.php), it will never reach the destination. So I believe your answer is not correct from that perspective. All I've seen so far in this respect shows the friendly URL on the browser, even when the starting point is the dynamic URL. I understand how this could work the other way around, but I cannot redirect to a php file without the php extension, AFAIK.

Comment: Don't give judgement until you understand how rewrite/redirect rules work. Now tell me what URL did you enter in browser and what was outcome?

Comment: I did try your solution before posting my comment, it gives a 404 error. There is no file /marques/.... It has to be marques.php as I pointed out above. Thanks.

Comment: You still didn't enter my question. What exact URL did you see in your browser? Also tell me what is location of your .htaccess? Are there more rules also?

Comment: The precise URL was /marques/39-Ford. The .htaccess is in the root directory and there are other rules pertaining to 404 error files, and gzipping, mainly.

Comment: But didn't you write: `I need it to show to the user and search engines as: www.example.com/marques/Ford`

Comment: Yes, I did write that and I've seen this done already. This is the whole point of differentiation in-between dynamic and SEO/user friendly URL.

Comment: You are contradicting then since your question says `/marques/Ford` and your comment says: `/marques/39-Ford`. Let me know what happens when you enter: `www.example.com/marques/Ford` in browser

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53846/discussion-between-bernarda-and-anubhava)